# Linked lists - Can't figure out why this remove last function is not working?

Tags: java, function, methods, linked-list

I made this remove last function and it seems like it should work, but when I call it, it doesn't actually remove anything, all of the nodes are still there.

Is there any problem with it?

```
  public Object removeLast()
    {
        Node currentNode;
        currentNode = this.getHead();
        while(currentNode != null)
        {

            if(currentNode.getNext()==null)
            {
               currentNode = null;
               return null;
            }
            currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list which contains nodes. Each node contains a pointer to the next node.

To remove a node from the list, you have to set the next pointer of the *previous* node to null

If you also have a pointer to the previous element, this is trivial. Something like:

```
public Object removeLast()
{
    Node currentNode;
    currentNode = this.getHead();
    while(currentNode != null)
    {

        if(currentNode.getNext()==null)
        {
           // The line below is changed!!!
           currentNode.getPrevious().setNext(null);
           return null;
        }
        currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
    }
    return null;
}
```

If you have a pointer in each node to the next as well as the previous node, then we call this a doubly-linked-list.

---

Also, there's no need for the return type to be `Object`, you can change your method signature to:

```
public void removeLast()
```

And then change each of your `return null;` to `return;`

Comment: I think you meant `public void removeLast()`. Mind you, it is not uncommon for remove methods to return the object they removed, so I expect changing the first `return null;` to be `return currentNode;` might be what is desired (who knows?) - that's of course assuming your modification is in place.

Comment: @fd. Agree with both points. I've corrected my signature suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

What you do now is that you set your dummy node to `null`, but that does not effect your list at all. I'll try to visualize:

Your original list consists of nodes, connected by next-pointers. The local variable `currentnode` refers to one of the nodes in the list. Below, it points to the last element.

```
head --<next>-> node --<next>-> node --<next>-> node --<next>-> null
                                                  ^
                                                  |
                                            currentnode
```

If you now do `currentnode = null`, this yields:

```
head --<next>-> node --<next>-> node --<next>-> node --<next>-> null


                                            currentnode --> null
```

Note that this does not affect your linked list at all.

---

What you want to do instead is set the `--<next>->` of the one-but-last node to `null`. For this, you should keep track of the previous node while iterating your list:

```
if (getHead().getNext() == null) {
    setHead(null);
} else {
    Node previous = getHead();
    Node current = previous.getNext();

    while (current.getNext() != null) {
        previous = current;
        current = current.getNext();
    }

    previous.setNext(null);
}
```